# Reducing an image size repeatedly with Imagemagick and filesize() php function

Tags: php, imagemagick

```
$path = 'images/test.jpg';
while(filesize($path) > 500000){
    system('convert ' . $path . ' -resize 50% ' . $path);
}
```

I have this simple code that uses Imagemagick to repeatedly reduce the size of `test.jpg` by half until it is smaller than 500 KB. However, this code is causing test.jpg to shrink indefinitely, as `filesize($path)` always reports the same number, so it is getting caught in the while loop forever. Does anyone know why `filesize($path)` is reporting the same number in each iteration of the loop, even though the image is in fact shrinking each time?

Comment: because you have already defined it and not updating it with the values inside while.. you just shrink the image but didn't check the filesize($path) again. Also `system('convert ' . $path . ' -resize 50% ' . $path);` system function requires second parameter but you only send one.

Comment: try `@exec($path . ' -resize 50% ',$output,1);` Here full description https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Image_lib.php This may help you out

Answer (score 0):

`filesize($path)` returns the same result on each iteration, because its results are cached, as [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) says:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

And, as the manual says, you should call [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) to clear that cache, so that you get the actual size of the file after you modify it with Imagemagick.